# Reutilização da Clausula AND (ORACLE)

Tags: query, oracle, where

Eai Galera.

Estou precisando executar um select onde fica muito repetitivo as minhas condições sendo varios joins na mesma tabela, Segue:

```
select
elfo.el_field_option_id "Centro de Custo ID", 
elfo.label "Centro de Custo", 
elfop_1.el_field_option_id "Empresa ID",
elfop_1.label "Empresa",
elfop_2.el_field_option_id "Unidade Gerencial ID",
elfop_2.label "Unidade Gerencial",
elfop_3.el_field_option_id "Segmento ID",
elfop_3.label "Segmento",
elfop_4.el_field_option_id "Sigla ID",
elfop_4.label "Sigla"
from el_field_option elfo
LEFT join el_field_option elfop_1 
    on elfop_1.el_field_option_parent_id = elfo.el_field_option_id
LEFT join el_field_option elfop_2 
    on elfop_2.el_field_option_parent_id = elfop_1.el_field_option_id
LEFT join el_field_option elfop_3 
    on elfop_3.el_field_option_parent_id = elfop_2.el_field_option_id
LEFT join el_field_option elfop_4 
    on elfop_4.el_field_option_parent_id = elfop_3.el_field_option_id
where elfo.el_field_id = 1620 
        AND ELFO.STATUS = 1 
        AND elfop_1.STATUS = 1 --DUVIDA AQUI
        AND elfop_2.STATUS = 1 --DUVIDA AQUI
        AND elfop_3.STATUS = 1 --DUVIDA AQUI
        AND elfop_4.STATUS = 1 --DUVIDA AQUI
        AND ELFO.STATUS = 1 --DUVIDA AQUI
        AND elfop_1.EL_FIELD_ID =1620
        AND elfop_2.EL_FIELD_ID = 1620 --DUVIDA AQUI
        AND elfop_3.EL_FIELD_ID = 1620 --DUVIDA AQUI
        AND elfop_4.EL_FIELD_ID = 1620; --DUVIDA AQUI
```

É possível passar apenas uma condição pra todas as colunas de status onde o "status" seja 1 e o EL_FIELD_ID = 1620?

Comment: Matematicamente você pode multiplicar todos os campos e testar se o resultado é 1, o que só ocorrerá se todos eles tiverem o valor 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pode fazer a ligação direto `JOIN` do `status` e do `el_field_id`:

```
...
from el_field_option elfo
LEFT join el_field_option elfop_1 
    on elfop_1.el_field_option_parent_id = elfo.el_field_option_id 
   and elfop_1.status = elfo.status
   and elfop_1.EL_FIELD_ID = elfo.EL_FIELD_ID
LEFT join el_field_option elfop_2 
    on elfop_2.el_field_option_parent_id = elfop_1.el_field_option_id 
   and elfop_2.status = elfop_1.status
   and elfop_2.EL_FIELD_ID = elfop_1.EL_FIELD_ID
LEFT join el_field_option elfop_3 
    on elfop_3.el_field_option_parent_id = elfop_2.el_field_option_id 
   and elfop_3.status = elfop_2.status
   and elfop_3.EL_FIELD_ID = elfop_2.EL_FIELD_ID
LEFT join el_field_option elfop_4 
    on elfop_4.el_field_option_parent_id = elfop_3.el_field_option_id 
   and elfop_4.status = elfop_3.status
   and elfop_4.EL_FIELD_ID = elfop_3.EL_FIELD_ID
 where elfo.el_field_id = 1620 
   AND ELFO.STATUS = 1
```